# Check active transactions in MySQL

Tags: mysql, delphi, delphi-xe, unidac

Is there a way to check the number of active transactions (on the database, not on the local UniConnection component) at any given time, using MySQL + UniConnection?

I'm trying to avoid deadlocks from extended operations and this way I could make one app wait until there are no ongoing active transactions executing from another app, into the same database.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the MySQL Command, [SHOW OPEN TABLES](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/show-open-tables.html), to determine if there is a lock on a table. The `in_use` column provides the number of table locks or lock requests for tables.

In which case, you could simply [LOCK TABLES](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/lock-tables.html) and `UNLOCK TABLES` around queries that are expected to have a long execution time.

Answer (score 2):

You can query the INFORMATION_SCHEMA for transaction related tables, I would refer to the Docs about it at MySQL: [Information Schema Tables about Transactions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-information-schema.html)